# Compare int outputs of the function and create a unitary score

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I have a pandas data frame with anomaly detection results from different models and I want to add another column that contains some kind of score or percentage i.e. how big is the possibility of this data point being an anomaly based on the scores given.
The goal ist basically to make the table more readable so that I could look and see the score that gives me some value and I won't have to count for each data point manually how many models classified the point as outlier and think further.

This was only an idea I had so I am not sure which tool should I use for that so I would be grateful for any help or tips.

FYI: the data frame, whereby 1 stands for outliers and 0 for inliers. also there is no labels or ground truth for this data.
[image: dataframe]

Comment: You can do a lot of things. You basically have classification problem given some parameters (score from model). Do you have the ground truth of your data? You could weight each model using some correlation analysis with the ground truth. Or given the 'accuracy' of each model. You could even train a new model on the scores...or cluster your table data...many ways to do what you seem to be implying.

Comment: no, sadly there is no ground truth. but training a new model on the scores sounds really interesting, I'll keep this in mind for future work, thanks.

Comment: With no ground truth, how do you validate your models? You could also try some clustering algorithms like RF to see if something pops up.

Comment: @JasonChia I haven't yet, I want to make labels later for future work